# want to display names separated by comma

Tags: angularjs

here is the program for display book details.everything is working perfect but i dont know how to display authorname separated by comma(,).I want to display author name separated by comma(,) in home page.the third line is error.that I want to fix and display authornames.

```
 home.html

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="display">
            <td>{{book.title}}</td>
      errorline:    <td>{{book.authorname}}</td>(Here i want to display author names separated by comma(,))
            <td>{{book.price}}</td>
            <td>
               <i class="material-icons"><button type="button" data-ng-click="editBook(book)">create</button></i>
            </td>
           <td><i class="material-icons"><button type="button" data-ng-click="deleteBook(book)">delete_forever</button></i></td>

        </script>
```

controllers.js

```
 $scope.online_bookauthors= 'data/bookauthors.js';
 $scope.loadbookauthorscadentials= function (file) {
    $http.get(file)
    .then(function (result) {
        $scope.bookauthorsresult=result;
        $scope.bookauthorslist=$scope.bookauthorsresult.data.bookauthorsdetails;

    })
 }

 $scope.loadbookauthorscadentials($scope.online_bookauthors);

bookauthors.js

{
    "bookauthors": {
        "Id": 1,
        "name": "Book Author Details"
    },
    "bookauthorsdetails": [{
        "bookid": 1,
        "title": "War and piece",
        "price": 100,
        "authors": [{
            "authorid": 1,
            "authorname": "Tolstoy"
        }, {
            "authorid": 2,
            "authorname": "Herman melville"
        }]

    }, {
        "bookid": 2,
        "title": "moby Dick",
        "price": 200,
        "authors": [{
            "authorid": 1,
            "authorname": "Tolstoy"
        }, {
            "authorid": 2,
            "authorname": "Herman melville"
        }, {
            "authorid": 3,
            "authorname": "Jane Austen"
        }]
    }],
    "selected": {}
}
```

Comment: use ng-repeat on bookauthorsdetails.authors and its easy.

Comment: If you have control over the data source, replace your value of "authorname" by your desired format. Doing this by hand for a couple entries is more efficient than writing code that catches all the edge cases (e.g. "Tolstoy", "Chris Van Allsburg", ...)

Comment: Sounds like I misunderstood the question, sorry. I thought you wanted to print out "last name, first name".

Comment: Its ok...now Its working jojonas..:) maybe your code is need me for future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div ng-repeat="author in book.authors">{{ ($index !== book.authors.length-1) ? author.authorname+',' : author.authorname }}</div>
```

Comment: So did that helped ?

Comment: I mean its display like Tolstoy,Herman melville,   no need to reapeat comma at the last elemnt

Comment: Sherin ... I think the best thing is to create another question and format the code as you did for the first question. The way you put it into a comment isn't right and comprehensible.
Show some respect to those who want to help you by at least well formatting your question

Comment: that I tried..but its only post the next question after 90 minutes.I need the answer immediately..thats why..sorry for that.I deleted that...

Comment: Ok I understand your point but I don't see any authordetails.js in your first code ... So I don't understand the question

Comment: its ok..I can understand..I will try after 90 minutes